# Как по клику на кнопку add all id вывести именно те id, по которым кликнул пользователь?

Tags: javascript, button, click

Всем привет, в задаче имеется родительский блок `<div class="parent-block">...</div>` имеющий в себе определенное количество дочерних блоков `<div class="child-block">...</div>` в свою очередь в каждом дочернем блоке находятся item с data-id. Задача заключается в том, что мне нужно получить только "кликнутые" data-id определенного родительского блока при нажатии на кнопку add all id, например в первом блоке пользователь кликнул по кнопкам 1, 3, 5 и после клика на add all id должно вывести в консоль 1, 3, 5 и т.д. Кнопка add all id собирает айдишки только со своего child-block. Если пользователь накликал в двух блоках child-block кнопки id, то должны вывестись именно те id, которые относятся ко своему child-block.
Можно ли как то решить задачу конкретно этим способом? Потому что у меня в работе это основной костяк в котором куча логики содержится.

```
parentBlock.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-all')) {...}})
```

Сам код:

```
<div class="parent-block">
  <div class="child-block" id="11">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="1">1</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="2">2</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="3">3</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="4">4</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="5">5</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-all">add all id</button>
  </div>
  <div class="child-block" id="12">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="6">6</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="7">7</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="8">8</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="9">9</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="10">10</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-all">add all id</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
let parentBlock = document.querySelector('.parent-block')
let item = document.querySelector('.item')
parentBlock.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-all')) {
    [...elem].filter(item => console.log(item.dataset.id))
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Здесь вам пригодится проход методом `forEach` по списку всех DOM-элементов, подходящих по селектору, собранных с помощью метода `querySelectorAll()`. `querySelector` находит лишь первое совпадение с селектором, а не все элементы. Повесить слушатель событий надо не `.parent-block`, а `.child-block`, поскольку самый верхний элемент содержит обе кнопки, а `.child-block` лишь свою. Фильтрацию кликнутых элементов я делаю благодаря выбору по селектору, но выбор произвожу методом `querySelector()` у элемента, а не у всего `document` для того, чтобы найти лишь вложенные `.item` элементы у конкретного `.child-block`. Я использую присваивание класса `clicked` для обозначения кликнутого элемента, используя метод `toggle()`, который берет в аргумент название класса и срабатывает как добавление класса, если его нет, или как удаление класса, если он есть.

Переменные, которые я не планирую переназначать я объявляю через `const`, поскольку так будет легче понимать код как минимум другим разработчикам.

Лично предпочитаю вешать обработчик на саму кнопку и проводить дальшейшие манипуляции вместо определения `event.target`, но написал под ваш код.

[Справка по element.toggle()](https://code.mu/ru/javascript/manual/dom/classList/toggle/)

[Справка по forEach для NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach)

[Справка по const](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const)

```js
const childBlock = document.querySelectorAll('.child-block')
const item = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

item.forEach( function(e){
  e.addEventListener('click', function(){
    this.classList.toggle('clicked');
  });
});

childBlock.forEach( (a) => {

  a.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if (e.target.classList.contains('btn-all')) {

      const thisChildren = this.querySelectorAll('.clicked');
      thisChildren.forEach( (el) => {
         console.log(el.querySelector('.elem').dataset.id);
      });
    }
  })

});
```

```css
.clicked {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent-block">
  <div class="child-block" id="11">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="1">1</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="2">2</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="3">3</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="4">4</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="5">5</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-all">add all id</button>
  </div>
  <div class="child-block" id="12">
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="6">6</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="7">7</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="8">8</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="9">9</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <span class="elem" data-id="10">10</span>
      <button class="btn">id</button>
    </div>
    <button class="btn-all">add all id</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за разъяснение, всё понятно и работает так как задумывалось. По поводу event.target, его определяю потому что банально в статьях про делегирование сразу пишут о данном свойстве как о некой панацее.

Comment: @AndrewKoshman array.from там лишний, обновил код, теперь он гораздо чище

Comment: Добрый день, спасибо еще раз, могу ли я вам задать еще вопрос по данной тематике? У меня по ходу разработки немножко изменилась верстка, вместо простой кнопки организовал счетчик и нужно выводить data-id в виде массива с айдишками [1, 3, 5] если value счетчика равен 1, а если value="2" например на 1 и 3 data-id, то выводить вот так [1, 1, 3, 3, 5]. Я уже сутки побороть не могу, может сможете подсказать как решить задачу. Вот ссылка на песочницу: https://jsfiddle.net/8ea6y94v/3/